# PKCS#11 API C_FindObjectsInit on a CKO_SECRET_KEY AES key segfaults

Tags: segmentation-fault, pkcs#11

I am using PKCS#11 to create a AES 256 bit key using C_GenerateKey. I then use C_FindObjectsxxx to search for the key handle and get a segfault.

Here is the code

```
static int find_object(CK_SESSION_HANDLE sess, CK_OBJECT_CLASS cls, CK_OBJECT_HANDLE_PTR ret, const unsigned char *id, size_t id_len, int obj_index)
{
      CK_ATTRIBUTE attrs[2];
      unsigned int nattrs = 0;
      CK_RV rv;

      attrs[0].type = CKA_CLASS;
      attrs[0].pValue = &cls;
      attrs[0].ulValueLen = sizeof(cls);
      nattrs++;

      rv = pfunc11->C_FindObjectsInit(sess, attrs, nattrs);    --> segfault
```

......

The call to C_GenerateKey appears successful or else this code would not have been called.

This is the call to the above code -

```
CK_OBJECT_HANDLE key;
if (find_object(session, CKO_SECRET_KEY, &key, id, sizeof(id), 0))
{
   printf("Key handle found\n");
}
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious bug here (but beware that `sizeof(id)` gives you size of a pointer instead of string length /use `strlen()` instead/ -- unless `id` is a macro with a string literal). Does this code segfault if you do not generate the key before calling it?

Comment: Thanks vlp. I got this resolved by doing inline calls to the functions. Not sure what was wrong but I did not spend time looking after the inline functions worked.